# In definition environment, citation font changes

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am using the bibliography style {plainnat}, and sometimes my citations have beautiful italic text, other times it is the same text as the paper. The code is the exact same so I have no idea why. I usually cite like this

```
\begin{definition}\cite[2.2, pg65]{serre2012course}{Ordinary Dirichlet Series}

\begin{theorem}\cite[Prop10.a, pg.69]{serre2012course}
```

For exapmle, the first code did note cite with nice italic text but second did. It seems definition environment does not use it.

Comment: Theorems are traditionally typeset in italics, while definitions are often typeset in upright/roman/"normal" font. The first citation is in a definition and would be "normal", whereas the second is in a theorem environment and thus in italics. Your bibliography style should have no control over this. ...

Comment: ... People often use the optional argument of `definition` and `theorem` for citations and titles, so you may want to try `\begin{definition}[Ordinary Dirichlet Series {\cite[2.2, p.~65]{serre2012course}}]` and `\begin{theorem}[{\cite[Prop~10.a, p.~69]{serre2012course}}]`. (These suggestions are a guess, your implementations of `definition` and `theorem` may differ from what the "standard packages" `amsthm` and friends do here.)

Comment: Please tell us more about how the `theorem` and `definition` environments are set up in your document. E.g., do you use a LaTeX package to help define these environments? If so, which ones? Are different `\theoremstyle` directives in force when the `theorem` and `definition` environments are created? Please also tell us more about the citation call-out style you employ: is the style numeric, authoryear, or something else? (The `plainnat` bib style can create citation callouts in several different styles, depending on the options passed to the `natbib` package.)